# Run Access query from Excel VBA with module name containing slash

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a MS Access query from Excel VBA. For that I'm using ADODB.Connection and ADODB.Command to call the query. In principle it works, but there is an issue with the name, because it contains slashes:  "Query_3/6/1/1". Running the script below, I get an error message like "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Query_3'." So it doesn't consider the rest of the name following the slash. I already tried escaping it with brackets [], but it doesn't help and other than that I didn't find a solution.

Renaming the module works, but there are lots of them and there are already other dependendies, so that is not really a solution.

I'm very glad for any help!

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

With con
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open "C:\Users\...\file.accdb"
End With

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = "Query_3/6/1/1"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open cmd
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to like the answer. I did some testing and Excel is just not going to honor that naming convention. I even called a query built from that Query_3/6/1/1 and it would not work. I encountered this same issue with queries that used Nz() function. Had to redesign queries.

Only alternative I can see is a procedure in Access that writes the query records to a 'temp table' (table is permanent, records are temporary) and the Excel calls this procedure then opens recordset based on the temp table.